# PHP Script not recognising given table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Finally I found some time to program my own website. The problem is, that it doesn't recognise the table that I'm giving him. I'm writing a guestbook based on SQL. It's logging into the SQL-platform, but simply doesn't get the database ... The name that I'm giving him is 100% spelled correctly! I've tried not to use the `$mysql_select_db` in my script, but naming the database in the "Select"-Statement & "Insert"-Statement. Doesn't work either >.<

Here're my scripts:

addguestbook.php

```
<?php

//******************************************************//
//********************Database stuff********************//
//******************************************************//
$host="localhost";                  // Host name
$username="";                       // Mysql username
$password="";                       // Mysql password
$db_name="mywebsite";               // Database name
//********************Tables***************************//
$tbl_name="guestbook";              // Guestbook

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $datetime=date("y-m-d h:i:s"); //date time

    // Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server ");
    //mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


    $sql="INSERT INTO $db_name.$tbl_name(name, email, website, comment, datetime)VALUES('$name', '$email', '$website', '$comment', '$datetime')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    mysql_close();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>

    <table width="700" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3"
        cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Test Sign Guestbook </strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="700" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0"
        cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
        <tr>
            <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post"
                action="index.php?mod=guestbook">
                <td>
                    <table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1"
                        bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="117">Name</td>
                            <td width="14">:</td>
                            <td width="357"><input name="name" type="text" id="name"
                                size="65" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Email</td>
                            <td>:</td>
                            <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="65" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Website</td>
                            <td>:</td>
                            <td><input name="website" type="text" id="website" size="65" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">Comment</td>
                            <td valign="top">:</td>
                            <td><textarea name="comment" cols="65" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> <input
                                type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="700" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3"
        cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td><strong><a href="viewguestbook.php">View Guestbook</a> </strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

viewguestbook.php

```
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><strong>View Guestbook | <a href="guestbook.php">Sign Guestbook</a> </strong></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>

<?php
//******************************************************//
//********************Database stuff********************//
//******************************************************//
$host="localhost";                  // Host name
$username="";                       // Mysql username
$password="";                       // Mysql password
$db_name="mywebsite";               // Database name
//********************Tables***************************//
$tbl_name="guestbook";              // Guestbook

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server ");
//mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $db_name.$tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td><table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="117">Name</td>
<td width="14">:</td>
<td width="357"><? echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><? echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">Comment</td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
<td><? echo $rows['comment']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">Date/Time </td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
<td><? echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Website</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><? echo $rows['website']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
</table>
<BR>
<?
}
mysql_close(); //close database
?>
```

edit: the errormessage:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects
>   parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in
>   C:\Anderes\xampp-win32-1.7.4-VC6\xampp\htdocs\MyWorkspace\MyWebsite\data\viewguestbook.php
>   on line 26

I've even put some lines of data into the table manually, doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you update the answer with any error messages you are getting?

Comment: maybe mysql is not  started by " /etc/init.d/mysqld start "

Comment: MySQL is started for sure ... I'm connecting on it, just not on the database

Comment: What exactly happens? What error messages do you get?

Comment: Also while `databasename.tablename` *should* work (I think), try `mysql_select_db($tablename)`

Comment: for debugging purpose try using select db

Comment: I've tried that! Check the code in approx. line 23. I'm getting the "or die ..."-Statement

Comment: Please read about SQL injection and use prepared statements before putting your website in public.

Comment: try this in your or die : `or die("cannot connect server :".mysql_error());`

Comment: ok ok, cannot select DB: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mywebsite'. I'll look for the username & password, even if it wasn't needed to enter it when accessing it via the browser. Thx for now

Answer (score 1):

```
  $sql="SELECT * FROM $db_name.$tbl_name";

 $sql="INSERT INTO $db_name.$tbl_name(name, email, website, comment, datetime)VALUES('$name', '$email', '$website', '$comment', '$datetime')";
```

> You should use following way $db_name
>   and $tbl_name are variables

```
  $sql="SELECT * FROM `".$db_name."` .`".$tbl_name."`";

$sql="INSERT INTO `".$db_name."` .`".$tbl_name."`(name, email, website, comment, datetime)VALUES('$name', '$email', '$website', '$comment', '$datetime')";
```

Comment: ya, thanks for the advice. I'm not that familiar with the syntax-style-stuff.

Answer (score 0):

in both files you are using `mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")`  it is wrong , you should use `mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)`    . then it should work .

Comment: it does also work the way I wrote it, but thanks :) it's working now - I just didn't know a username was existing -.-'

Answer (score 0):

Try this updated code please and give result.

```
// Connect to server and select database.
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die(mysql_error());

$sql="INSERT INTO $db_name.$tbl_name(name, email, website, comment, datetime)VALUES('$name', '$email', '$website', '$comment', '$datetime')";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$conn);

mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you blanked out the username and password values for security here.
The code looks okay to me as you have it.
On my server, the database name is prefixed by my primary login name.
So "mywebsite" would be "myname_mywwebsite".
Make sure you have the database and table names spelled correctly.